# I have an error with Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, sdk

I have a problem, who can help me?

I made a application before 3 Months , with Android Studio 3.
I tryed to open the application with Android Studio 2 but does't work .
So now I installed Android Stuido 3 but also It does't work :(

This my Gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.1.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.learnjava.vgpro"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 4
        versionName "3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.4'

}
```

This is the Problem :

```
Error:(23, 0) Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\JamilHammash\Desktop\LearnJava\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

update your gradle version to version 3, for example

```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-rc2'
```

otherwise replacing:

```
testImplementation with testCompile
```

an

```
implementation with compile
```

should help